# Why doesn't my screen lock in XFCE?

Tags: arch-linux, xfce, screen-lock

I'm trying out XFCE on Arch Linux, and for some reason the Lock Screen option in the session menu doesn't do anything.  Neither does running `xflock4` at the command line (it exits 0 with no output).

`xfce4-session` is running.

Do I need to install a screensaver package or something?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> Do I need to install a screensaver package or something?

Yes, [according to the wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xfce#Lock_the_screen), you need to choose and install a locker. `xflock4` will then activate it.

Comment: Actually, gnome-screensaver is installed, and it was working under Gnome.  Do I need to activate it somehow?

Comment: Ok, the problem seems to be that `gnome-screensaver-command` exists, but `gnome-screensaver` is not running.  `xflock4` runs `gnome-screensaver-command --lock`, which does nothing but exits 0, so `xflock4` thinks it's done.

Comment: I prefer [i3lock](http://i3wm.org/i3lock/) as a simple screen locker, which isn't directly supported by `xflock4`, so I wrote a simple wrapper script as `/usr/bin/xscreensaver-command` that invokes `i3lock`.  Since `xflock4` tries `xscreensaver-command` before `gnome-screensaver-command`, that fixes the problem.

Comment: `slock` is even simpler and now comes with a feature: colour!

Comment: @jasonwryan: Ugh, just a gimmicky trend.  Colour display is no more useful than having over 640k of RAM...

Comment: Need to run `xfce4-screensaver &` after installing it too. I was wondering why it didn't work after install.

Comment: In Debian bookworm (stable 2023) the command "xfce4-screensaver" is not an available package.

Answer (score 12):

First install `light-locker`.

```
$ xfconf-query -c xfce4-session -p /general/LockCommand -s "light-locker-command -l"
```

or if you don't have the variable yet:

```
$ xfconf-query -c xfce4-session -p /general/LockCommand -s "light-locker-command -l" --create -t string
```

---

---

---

**Old stuff:**

Looks like `xflock4` does support external config now. What I did is:

```
$ xfconf-query -c xfce4-session -p /general/LockCommand -s "dm-tool lock"
```

Now that command is used for locking. I guess gnome-screen-saver broke on upgrade.

This is for XFCE. If you don't have that property already, you add it by:

```
$ xfconf-query -c xfce4-session -p /general/LockCommand -s "dm-tool lock" --create -t string
```

**VERY IMPORTANT:** you need a screensaver running to securely lock your screen. `light-locker` is one choice. At the end make sure switching consoles with ctrl+alt+F1 or some other F# does not let you circumvent the lock screen. See:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lxsession/+bug/1205384
- https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1300178

Comment: Thanks! I'm a migrating from XFCE4 to BSPWM, now i3lock works great!

Answer (score 8):

[Edit](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xfce#Lock_the_screen) `/usr/bin/xflock4` and append `light-locker-command -l` or `dm-tool lock` to the list.

```
for lock_cmd in \
"xscreensaver-command -lock" \
"gnome-screensaver-command --lock" \
"light-locker-command -l"\
"dm-tool lock"
```

Comment: This also works for Linux Mint 19, if anyone is looking for that.

Comment: i was trying to use slock, built from source. slock is used as a fallback locker by default, but if you build from source you need to add `/usr/local/bin` to the path up top.

Comment: Thanks, just adding a shortcut to ```dm-tool lock``` to Keyboard does the job

Answer (score 2):

Case_of's answer was close for me, but dm-tool was already listed in my 
 `/usr/local/bin/xflock4`. But it tried `xscreensaver-command` and `gnome-screensaver-command` first. I moved those to the second for loop, and moved dm-tool up as the only option at first (removing the first for loop):

```
dm-tool lock >/dev/null 4>&1 && exit

# else run another access locking utility, if installed
for lock_cmd in \
  "xscreensaver-command -lock" \
  "gnome-screensaver-command --lock"
  "xlock -mode blank" \
  "slock"
  do
    set -- $lock_cmd
    if command -v -- $1 >/dev/null 2>&1; then
        $lock_cmd >/dev/null 2>&1 &
    # turn off display backlight:
    xset dpms force off
        exit
    fi
done
```

I also mapped it to <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, to be like Windows.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem and resolved it when I turned on Lock Screen in `Settings`>`Screensaver`>`Lock Screen`

[image: Lock Screen settings]

Comment: u save me thx @almaceleste

Answer (score 1):

`/usr/bin/xscreensaver` was not running. Fixed by opening `xfce4-settings-manager`, opening screen saver section, it asked to run xscreensaver daemon, clicked yes and the locking works now.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `loginctl` to lock the system. 
in order to lock the screen you can simply do :

```
loginctl lock-session
```

You can selectively lock a specific session by providing a session id

```
loginctl lock-session sid
```

you can check the [documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/loginctl.html) for more information

Answer (score 0):

I just (January 2018) tried to get screen locking working under XFCE.  I'm a little surprised it didn't work by default.  I initially tried to install `light-locker` and `xscreensaver` but neither worked.

What worked for me was to install the `xlockmore` package which provided `/usr/bin/xlock` which seems to work great.  With that command now installed, I was able to configure the xfce session to use it:

```
xfconf-query -c xfce4-session -p /general/LockCommand -s "xlock"
```

or if you don't have the variable yet:

```
xfconf-query -c xfce4-session -p /general/LockCommand -s "xlock" --create -t string
```

My `/usr/bin/xflock4` script already pays attention to that `LockCommand` setting so there was no need to edit the script once I had the setting applied.

Xlock has a ton of different modes and settings which, by default, it randomizes through.  I settled on:

```
xlock -mode goop -erasedelay 0
```

To test them use:

```
xlock -mode ... -nolock
```

Answer (score 0):

Really weird, but

```
xscreensaver-command --lock
```

worked after enabled on the Screensaver preferences (GUI of Xscreensaver) the option "Lock screen after", and edit keyboard lock shortcut to the command above

obs: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS with xfce4 4.14